# Add class to <ul> if there are more than 2 <li> nested

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Have something like this:

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

And I need to add a class to the ul element if there are more than 3 items nested.

Comment: Updated my post, sorry.

Comment: @JAVIERMARTINBALSA that is a code sample, not what you have tried ;) anyhow some answers are already provided :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to can get you desired `ul > li`, then you can easily check length and apply class

```js
var liList = document.getElementById("mylist").getElementsByTagName("li");
if (liList.length > 3) {
    document.getElementById("mylist").className += " customlist";
}
```

```css
.customlist {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist" class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a query selector, and check how many `li` elements are direct children of the `ul`:

```js
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")];
if (items.length > 3) {
  document.querySelector("ul").classList.add("lots");
}
```

```css
.lots {
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the count of items in your UL, and then if the count is more than 3 then add the class...

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var itemCount = $("ul > li").length
    console.log(itemCount);
    if(itemCount => 3) {
      $("ul").addClass("className");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping code you want to run might b dynamic where you only want to add CSS class on  tag when list is greater than 3.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
listItems.length > 3 ? listItems[0].parentNode.classList.add("my-ul-class"): 
listItems[0].classList.remove("my-ul-class");
```

```css
.my-ul-class {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var liList = document.getElementById("mylist").getElementsByTagName("li");
if (liList.length > 3) {
    document.getElementById("mylist").className += " customlist";
}
```

```css
.customlist {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist" class="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```